# Find every 6 hours from now

Tags: javascript, datetime

I need to find a set of hours, starting from now, every 6 hours.

So if now is midnight, I want `[ 0, 6, 12, 18 ]`.
If now is 15h (3pm), I want `[ 15, 21, 3, 9 ]`

For now I have brute-forced it:

```
var now = new Date();
var hours = [];
var h = now.getHours();
// add current hour (tomorrow)
hours.push(h);

// to add 6 hours
var inXh = function(toAdd) {
    var inh = h + toAdd;
    if (inh >= 24) { inh = inh - 24; }
    return inh;
}; 

// add in 6 hours
hours.push(inXh(6));
// add in 12 hours
hours.push(inXh(12));
// add in 18 hours
hours.push(inXh(18));
```

It's incredibly ugly and verbose, and I'm sure there is a much more clever way to do it, but right now I'm too tired to calculate modulos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are basically calculating the modulo manually by doing

```
if (inh >= 24) { inh = inh - 24; }
```

but JavaScript can do it for you, so the `inXh()` function could be written like this:

```
var inXh = function(toAdd) {
    return (h + toAdd * 6) % 24;
}
```

With that, after having declared

```
var h = new Date().getHours();
```

you have (at least) two options, choose the one you feel more elegant.

**OPTION 1: using `for`:**

```
var hours = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) hours.push(inXh(i));
```

**OPTION 2 (nicer in my opinion): using [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):**

```
var hours = [0, 1, 2, 3].map(inXh);
```

which all together in one line would be

```
var hours = [0, 1, 2, 3].map(function(toAdd) { return (h + toAdd * 6) % 24; });
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a more general answer you could think about wrapping it into a function where you can specify the starting number, the offset, and the max number and then have it generate the whole set for you. Right now your `inXh` function depends on `h` above which will make it difficult to reuse. A more general function would look something like this:

```
function inXh(start, offset, max) {
    // implementation
}
```

Now for the implementation. Let's start by thinking about your second example with start=15, offset=6, and max=24. All of the numbers you want can be generated by adding 6 to 15 and then applying mod 24 to the result, the problem is where to begin and end. If you keep adding 6 to 15 you get `[15, 21, 27, 33, 39, 45, 51, ...]`. Applying mod 24 to these numbers you get `[15, 21, 3, 9, 15, 21, 3, ...]`. You can see the pattern starts to repeat at 39, which is actually 15 + 24 (or start + max), this makes sense because 24 mod 24 is 0 so we end up back where we started. Using this knowledge and renaming your function to something slightly clearer, you could get something like the following:

```
function getHourSet(start, offset, max) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = start; i < start + max; i = i + offset) {
    result.push(i % max);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Now your usage code is also much easier:

```
var now = new Date();
var hours = getHourSet(now.getHours(), 6, 24);
```